# Native skip_if_condition()

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop, continue

### Continue

> continue is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration [(from: php.net)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

I recently learned about the `continue` structure of PHP. In short, for those who aren't yet aware: to break off a (foreach/while/for)loop iteration, one could write the following:

```
if($foo == 0){
    continue;
}
```

*(If $foo is 0, the loop will skip the current iteration and continue with the next.)*

### On to the question

For those who (like me) just had a eureka experience, good for you! However, seeing the code made me think about the formatting of code like this. As you've probably noticed, the above statement takes up 3 lines of your script. Surely you could write the entire statement on 1 line but that wouldn't add much in ways of readability.

For now, I'll write my own 'native' function something along the lines of:

```
skip_if_null( (int) $foo = null);
skip_if_more( (int) $foo, (int) $bar = 0);
skip_if_less( (int) $foo, (int) $bar = 0);
```

But I'd rather use a native PHP method to achieve the same result, in one statement. 
 
**So is there such a native function included in PHP? And if not, how come there isn't?**

Comment: *the above statement takes up 3* - and your point is?  Unless your code contains quite a few of these (which may indicate a structure problem) then it isn't that significant to put up with for the sake of clarity.

Comment: _“And if not, how come there isn't?”_ - why should there be? This feels a bit like if you were asking, “we all know the result of 2 plus 2 is 4, right? So why is there no function `result_of_2_plus_2()`, that returns the value `4`?” – well, because that would be so terribly ultra-specific, that it really makes little sense.

Comment: @NigelRen I understand your confusion, I should have clarified: Since my focus is on writing clean readable code I'd expect the PHP community (hence, PHP 7.x) to have tackled this gap in functionality. Besides the point, what you may find 'not that significant' might actually be in a different situation. To prepare myself for such an occasion in the future, I'd like to know more.

Comment: *I'd expect the PHP community... to have tackled this gap in functionality*, perhaps look at it the other way - if no-one else has come up with this, then perhaps the gap isn't as significant as you think!

Comment: @NigelRen That's a different, maybe slightly more passive way of thinking but I think I get your point: Try not to over-engineer what doesn't need to be. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: One thing is that it is good to challenge things and try and gain a better understanding of what is already there.  It's like writing your own framework, it helps understand some of the issues that other frameworks solve and why some things are done the way they are.

Comment: @NigelRen Very true, I appreciate your challenging engagement; it has done exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the statement can already be placed on one line; you can also leave off the braces, making it feel more like a single statement:

```
if ( $foo == 0 ) continue;
```

> So is there such a native function included in PHP? And if not, how come there isn't?

"Why" is always a slippery question, but in general, we could ask why programming languages include statements like `continue` rather than functions like `skip_if_more($foo, $bar)`. A few thoughts come to mind:

- Flexibility: a `continue` statement can be used with any condition you can imagine; you'd need a long list of `skip_if...` functions just to cover the common cases, and still need some way to give a custom condition if none of them matched.
- Easier to define: `continue` has to do something special in the run-time engine that a normal function call couldn't; any `skip_if...` function would have to be included as a special case.
- Easier to understand: glancing at code and seeing the word `continue`, you can immediately see that it's going to control the loop; glancing at a call to `skip_if_array_is_empty`, you would have to guess if this was a built-in function or an unrelated custom one.
- Easier to learn: you've only just discovered `continue`; imagine if you had to learn a dozen specific `skip_if...` functions, and a dozen more `return_if...`, and so on...

Comment: Great explanation. You've taken away the need to write a custom function and you've given insight in why a native function like this wouldn't exist. Thanks!